# Serial port some of the frames received are displaced or missing data

Tags: c#, serial-port

I communicates with the device over the serial port with the speed 512000. All serial port settings:

```
SerialPort = new SerialPort();
SerialPort.BaudRate = 512000;
SerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
SerialPort.DataBits = 8;
SerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
SerialPort.ReadTimeout = 2000;
SerialPort.WriteTimeout = 2000;
```

I am hooked to the DataReceived event and read data in this way:

```
private bool statusRead;
private async void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (statusRead)
            return;
        statusRead = true;
        while (SerialPort.BytesToRead == 7)
            await Task.Delay(1);
        byte[] bufferHeader = new byte[7];
        SerialPort.Read(bufferHeader, 0, bufferHeader.Length);
        while (SerialPort.BytesToRead < bufferHeader[4] - 7)
            await Task.Delay(1);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferHeader[4] - 7];
        SerialPort.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        if (Crc.CheckCrc(ref buffer, 0, buffer.Length, BitConverter.ToUInt16(bufferHeader, 5)))
        {
            ...
        }
        else
        {
            ...
            SerialPort.ReadExisting();
        }
        statusRead = false;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        statusRead = false;
    }
    if (SerialPort.BytesToRead > 0)
        port_DataReceived(null,null);
}
```

When reading frames, the most common occurrence is that the frame does not have a first byte. Or some data is out of place. Am I able to do something on the C # side to prevent this from happening?

It expects a frame that looks like this:

> 11 26 19 0 16 102 143 7 27 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

but I get for example:

> 26 19 0 16 102 143 7 27 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

> 11 26 19 0 16 102 0 143 7 27 0 0 0 0 0 0

I've done a few serial port applications before, but I've never communicated with this speed. Is speed the cause of such errors? I analyzed the outgoing frames from the board and they are as they should be. Then this data is sent to the second board which I am connected, but I am not able to analyze what the frames look like there.

Comment: Your concept of *"frame"* in the context of a serial port is incorrect.  A UART frames each byte or character.  There is no concept of framing for messages or datagrams using asynchronous serial connections at the data link level.  Software (e.g. your program) is responsible for identifying the start & end of each message or datagram or line.

Comment: You have a framing issue.  There is no guarantee that what is sent in one write will be read in one chunk.  The serial port in windows is implemented using timers and the timers may break a message into multiple chunks.   So you need to create a buffer that combines all the receive data into one list and then parse the results from the list.  You also may need to flush the buffer when application starts.  For example if you are reading a scale and the scale is automatically continuously sending weights.  Then you application starts the first message received may not be a complete weight.

Comment: @sawdust : You are mixing up the transport layer with the application layer.  What you are saying is correct at the transport layer, but not at the application layer.  A well designed asynchronous serial port you need to separate the transport layer from the application layer.

Comment: @jdweng I don't know if that's what you meant, but instead of attaching to the DataReceived event, I read byte in new Task an infinite loop, check the BytesToRead> 0 condition in the loop and save it to the buffer, which it then analyzes. Now the data is being read correctly, but I don't quite understand why I didn't get the same effect in my way. There I checked if I had enough data and I did not skip any byte and read everything in order.

Comment: @jdweng -- I haven't *"mixed up"* anything.  The OP is expecting a read syscall on an asynch serial device to maintain *message* framing.  I stated that there is no such *message* framing at the UART; at that hardware level the only framing is for char/byte.   I pointed out that the OP's program (or by your preferred terminology, the *"application layer"*) is responsible for *message* framing.